# Is it possible to "chain" Istio AuthorizationPolicies?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization, istio

I have a question about using AuthorizationPolicy to accomplish a specific scenario. In particular, I have set things up with a CUSTOM action and OAuth2-Proxy so that traffic hitting my Ingress Gateway, targeted to host httpbin.example.com, is sent through OAuth2-Proxy and Dex for login. After logging in I am then able to access the httpbin pod, as expected.

But… what I would like to do is further processing after the login, so I can, for example, permit access to a particular workload for some whitelisted set of users, but not “everybody who can login” and then conversely gate access to a different workload to a different set of users.

My naive thought would be to have the initial CUSTOM action based AuthorizationPolicy scoped to the Ingress Gateway to trigger the OAuth login, and then have subsequent AuthorizationPolicies scoped to the specific workloads, and that inspect the user principal from the headers provided by the OAuth flow.

Is this a reasonable understanding? If not, is there another way to achieve the same overall effect?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct understanding. CUSTOM AuthorizationPolicy is evaluated first and you can then use another ALLOW/DENY policy after that. https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/security/#implicit-enablement

I see 2 choices how to achieve your scenario:

1. Configure `--set-authorization-header` flag in OAuth2 Proxy to forward JWT token in Authorization header to upstream service. Then setup Istio [RequestAuthentication](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/request_authentication/) to verify and parse that token and check role in regular AuthorizationPolicy.

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: jwt-authentication
spec:
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: https://<your-issuer-uri>
    jwksUri: https://<your-jwks-uri>
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      # match your workload
      app: my-workload
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: roles-policy
spec:
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
  - when:
    - key: request.auth.claims[groups]
      values:
      - admin
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      # match your workload
      app: my-workload
```

2. Another option is to enable `--set-xauthrequest` flag in OAuth2 Proxy and then check e.g. value of `X-Auth-Request-Groups` header in Istio AuthorizationPolicy. But you must make sure that nobody can bypass OAuth2 Proxy and fake this header.

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: roles-policy
spec:
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
  - when:
    - key: request.headers[X-Auth-Request-Groups]
      values:
      - admin
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      # match your workload
      app: my-workload
```

Also don't forget to add `Authorization` or `X-Auth-Request-Groups` header to `headersToUpstreamOnAllow` in Istio [authz provider configuration](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/istio.mesh.v1alpha1/#MeshConfig-ExtensionProvider-EnvoyExternalAuthorizationHttpProvider).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try both of these scenarios and try to get it working.